# Adding custom fields to Bills and Adjustment screen causes "nullable object must have a value"

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization to the Bills and Adjustments screen (AP301000), where I'm simply adding 4 user fields to the Document Details tab's grid.  *I've done this many, many times in the past and I've never seen this error*.  I have absolutely NO idea what would cause it.

**Here's the DAC extension:**

```
[PXCacheName("AP Tran Extension")]
public class APTranExt : PXCacheExtension<APTran>
{

    #region UsrACAllocModule
    [PXDBString(30, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Allocation Module")]
    public virtual string UsrACAllocModule { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrACAllocModule : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrACAllocModule> { }
    #endregion

    #region UsrACAllocBatch
    [PXDBString(30, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Allocation Batch")]
    public virtual string UsrACAllocBatch { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrACAllocBatch : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrACAllocBatch> { }
    #endregion

    #region UsrACAllocLineNbr
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Allocation LineNbr")]
    public virtual int? UsrACAllocLineNbr { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrACAllocLineNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrACAllocLineNbr> { }
    #endregion

    #region UsrACAllocationID
    [PXDBString(30, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Allocation ID")]
    public virtual string UsrACAllocationID { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrACAllocationID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrACAllocationID> { }
    #endregion

}
```

**The database fields exist as follows:**

[image]

**Here is how the fields are added:**

[image]

**And here is the error:**

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce it.  I just added the 4 fields to a sandbox copy of 2019R2 and added the fields to the grid without any trouble.  I used your DAC via copy/paste on the field definitions.  By chance, do you still get an error if you remove the fields from the grid and refresh the page?  And then get the error again when you put them back on the grid?  Perhaps try adding 1 field at a time to see if you can narrow down which one is causing the issue.

Comment: FYI - this is for 2020 R1 (build 20.102.0015)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ran across the same issue. It is a bug in Acumatica. It is resolved in build 20.104.

Comment: And there's nothing you can do about it. It requires an Acumatica update to fix it.

Comment: Great.  Thanks, all!... ;D